# Can someone give me a regular expression for a number to be between 1 and 5

Tags: regex

Can someone give me a regular expression for a number to be between 1 and 5, single digit

e.g. input has to be a number between 1 and 5 , 55 or 23 would not match

Comment: Why use a regular expression in this case when you can use condition expression which will perform much better.

Comment: Does `between` mean inclusive 1 and 5 (1,2,3,4,5) or exclusive (2,3,4)?

Comment: Which regex flavor/engine? What programming language? When you say "number" do you mean "integer"? And does it need to be a regex? Regex is the wrong tool for doing math.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
/^[1-5]$/
```

Explanation:

```
^     Start of line/string.
[1-5] A digit between 1 and 5.
$     End of line/string.
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be simpler to check it as a number (ie if(x>=1 && x<=5) or something similar) rather than using a regex?

Comment: it depends on whether the programming language converts strings to numbers automatically, or requires you to call methods and deal with exceptions in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Much more concise to say

```
if(x> 0 and x<5)
```

IMHO

Comment: Right, if `between` means exclusive 1 and 5.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this should do
    [1-5]

Comment: No it wouldn't, since it would match 12345 or 5555 or this5is_not_a_number.

Comment: @Paul: No, it would match the 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 in 12345.

Comment: @splash, that's the problem - if you fed it '12345' or 'this5is_not_a_number', it would say it matched, because it matched one part of the string.  If you want to make it exclusive, as the original question asked, then you need anchors like @Mark Byers said.

Comment: @Paul, you are right in context of the original question, but your phrasing `it would match 12345` is imprecise as to @Faisal's regular expression `[1-5]`. ;-)

Comment: @splash, excuse me for thinking that an answer to the question should answer "in the context of the original question".